# Excluding IP addresses from Country Redirection

Tags: php, exception, geoip

I have this block of code that currently redirects anyone in Canada to the Canadian version of our site:

```
<?php
require_once('geoip.inc');
$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
// prints the country code  your visitor is in
if($country == 'CA')
{
header('Location: http://www.WEBSITE.ca');
exit();
}
// the end
geoip_close($gi);?>
```

What I am wondering is how can I exclude an IP address of someone in Canada from automatically being redirected so that they can also access the US and EU versions of our site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another condition to the if statement.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($country == 'CA' && $ip !== '127.0.0.1')
{
   header('Location: http://www.WEBSITE.ca');
   exit();
}
```

$ip will be the ip address of the person that is currently viewing the site. 
You can get this with:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: OP should also allow the user to *choose* whether or not they want to be redirected, and store that preference in a Session var.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` in the `if` statement to add additional conditions such as "Remote address is not equal to this string".